# Identify location of infected files Clamscan says it found without sucess

Tags: malware

I am using a [devuan](https://devuan.org/) system and while doing `clamscan -r -i /` the clamscan report shows up two infected files.

However clamscan do not seem to create any log of the searching so I am stuck knowing my operating system could be infected without being able to do anything about it!

How could I find the infected files clamscan reports? Trying to generate a report of the scan in txt does not seem to work. The `-z` option does not seem to work either

Any help regarding this would be very helpful

Comment: Do the files show up when you run the scan again?